# How can I run commands in nested SSH connections in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to write a script which will connect to the server and run some utils there.

So, if I want to connect to the server, I do

```
ssh $server << EOF
run
some
commands
EOF
```

And it works properly.
But if I want to do nested ssh connection, I'm doing like this:

```
ssh $server_1 << EOF
ssh $server_2 << EOF
run some commands
EOF
```

I guess it works properly, but I'm receiving error messages
Do you know how to use "nested" EOFs properly?
I know that I can run

```
ssh $server 'run|some|commands'
```

but there are a lot of commands here and I cant write it into a line

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two different "end of here-document" delimiters:

```sh
ssh $server_1 << EOF1
ssh $server_2 << EOF2
run some commands
EOF2
EOF1
```

Or better yet, use an "SSH jump host" like this:

```sh
ssh -J $server_1 $server_2 << EOF
run some commands
EOF
```